# Modify input type=number to have arrows on either side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change input type=number to have arrows on either side. So instead of having the spinner at the right hand side, I wish to have a left arrow to the left and a right arrow to the right.

So that is how I want an input to look like:
[This Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeWvz.png)

Comment: This [BootstrapTouchSpinner ](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/) is useful to you.

Comment: You can simply create your own custom input without resorting to input type=number. You can use simple text box, and bind event to left and right arrows.

Comment: Ramachandra Reddy, thank you very much. It's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can design your own arrows i.e left and right as you said,then use jquery spinner plugin hide their up /down arrows, and call their click handlers on your arrows.